# Single Q/A Per Page (Conditional) Workflow Application

Tags: web-applications, conditional-statements, opml

I'm currently working with students who have ADHD and am trying to set up a system (preferably a website) that takes a decision tree we have made (exported to OPML) and displays it one question per page, but moves to a yes/no branch of the tree based on the answer given. It would be nice if we could also have text input for questions in a series, but right now we'd be happy with yes & no.

It seems very simple, but I can't find anything like it online, but maybe I'm just not using the proper words when looking on Google.

If it helps, the structure would be like this: **Q1(Y/N) if Y goto Q2, if N goto END**.

Thanks very much in advance.

---

Edit: This might also be considered guided help. I believe this software is similar to what I'm looking for, but not exactly it [MapIt Designer](http://www.mapitdesigner.com/).

Comment: Cross posted on Programmers - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131754/guided-q-a-software-with-conditional-branches